# When trying to run a test train split, I am running into a key error, what should I do?

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I'm having an issue when running the following code, I have no idea what to do:

```
fd2['Close'] = fd2['Close'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == '300' else 0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(fd2['Volume_(BTC)'].values, fd2['Close'].values)
```

---

```
KeyError                                  
Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/traviskerr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, 
tolerance)
   2392             try:
-> 2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2394             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 
(pandas/_libs/index.c:5239)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 
(pandas/_libs/index.c:5085)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
(pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20405)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
(pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20359)()

KeyError: 'Close'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What this will often times mean is that your dataframe does not contain a `'Close'` column. 
Trailing whitespaces or wrong upper/lowercase characters can be the source. Make sure that your actual column name is not like

`' Close'`
or
`'close'`
.

Comment: i think the easiest way to check it is: `print(fd2.columns.tolist())`